# Is this a known Rails Manager pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am going through a co-workers code and am not able to find a single tutorial where this has been used. Can someone point me to some resources where this has been used. This has made code very clean but I haven't found any reference to it. This is only part of this class. It includes other some more methods.

```
class Manager
        include ActiveModel::Model
        include ActiveModel::Associations

      attr_accessor :application_id, :user_id, :user_application_id,.........
      belongs_to :application
      belongs_to :user_application
      belongs_to :user .. more belongs .......

       # This method is necessary to enable this ActiveModel Class to be used in views along with Form helpers
      def self._reflect_on_association(association) #:nodoc:
       _reflections[association.to_sym]
      end

      def []=(attr, value)
        self.send("#{attr}=", value)
      end

      def [](attr)
        multi_attribute_ids = [:some_ids.to_s, :someid2.to_s]
        return if multi_attribute_ids.include?(attr)
        self.send(attr)
      end
      def applicant_name 
      end
      -- some more methods
end
```

What would be the use of such a "manager". What are the two methods that are using self.send doing here. Is this a common pattern in rails.

Comment: Where's your co-worker?

Comment: `def []=(attr, value)` and `def [](attr)` are brackets setters and getters. They are called when you do `manager[:foo]` and `manager[:foo] = 'bar'`.

Comment: Ruby has plenty of these odd looking methods (like `+` , `==`, `<=>`) since most operators are just methods.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with the introduction of ActiveModel in Rails 3, it has become an increasingly common pattern to use domain objects (called a manager in this case) that are not backed by an actual database table but which look and feel like models.

Even though ActiveModel makes it [particularly convenient](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html) to pick and choose Rails model features to be incorporated into arbitrary classes, this pattern is something Rails pioneers [have been](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/activemodel-model-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) [encouraging](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) since a long time.

As has been illustrated clearly in the example you posted, this pattern allows us to define virtual models and virtual associations which can easily take advantage of form helpers and other rails niceties written assuming model objects.

Comment: Yeah ..Thanks for the link .. I had seen this before. This code doesn't use  reflect_on_association(association) .. However we had to add this , our code was breaking in coffeescript without adding this.